# No me funciona el agregar option dinamica en Chrome

Tags: javascript, select, chrome

esta es mi primera vez aca ya que estoy aprendiendo mas en profunidad el tema de la programación. Tengo un problema que es que tengo un select con options agregadas dinamicamente , pero solo se visualiza bien el MOZilla, en Chrome no se visualizan, pero cuando inspeccionas estan puestas, les dejo mas o menos el cod:

```
<script>

    $.getJSON("kits.json", function (kitjson) {

                    for (i = 0; i < kitjson.kits.length; i++) {

                        var valorKitname = kitjson.kits[i].kitname
                        var x = document.getElementById("selectKit");
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = valorKitname;
                        x.add(option);

                    }
                });
</script>

 <select id="selectKit"  >
                <option>Mustard</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>          
 </select>
```

Si alguno sabe se lo agradeceria ! Exitos !

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente en Chrome, algo más se te está escapando

Comment: Hola ! gracias por la respuesta, lo voy a seguir revisando !

Comment: el problema es que al abrir el archivo, si lo abro desde la carpeta como un file con doble click chrome no me ejecuta el jquery, mozilla si. Asi que lo probé desde un servidor y me lo visualizo perfecto el chrome.